# How to Null Check?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, testcase

My application developed by C# (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, version 6.0.25).

I am using Moq (version 4.20.70) and NUnit (version 4.0.1) for unit test cases

I tried below method to null check,

```
[TestCase(null)]
public void TestCreateClient_ShouldThrowException_IfPasswordIsNull(string certificatePassword)
{
    //Arrange
    var clientFactory = new ClientFactory(_mockRepositoryWrapper.Object, _alertService.Object);

    //Act
    var exception = Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => clientFactory.CreateClientAsync(certificatePassword, TestValues.CERTIFICATE_BASE64, TestValues.APP_ID, TestValues.DOMAIN, TestValues.CUSTOMER_ID, TestValues.ENVIRONMENT_ID, TestValues.LOCALE));

    //Assert
    Assert.That(exception.ParamName, Is.EqualTo("certificatePassword can not be null or empty"));
}
```

but i got below error

**error NUnit1001: The value of the argument at position '0' of type `<null>` cannot be assigned to the parameter 'certificatePassword' of type string**

Comment: First of all, if you only have a single test case, why are you passing in a parameter in the first place? Secondly, if you want it to allow nulls, then the parameter type should be `string?`

Comment: @DavidG I actually have more than 1 test case where I pass an empty string too ie [TestCase("")] and I could use string? but the function being tested only allows strings and I get a compiler warning when I use string? as the parameter in the Test function.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77745245/edit) the question and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The test name here is specific to nulls though, so you should not be passing empty string. Make a new test for empty string. Also I just noticed that you are testing the `ParamName` property against an error message. ParamName should only contain `certificateName` here so I would check how you are throwing that exception, perhaps you have mixed up your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding ! after null like this -> [TestCase(null!)] should resolve the error you're encountering. This tells the compiler to treat null as a valid value for the certificatePassword parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When using NUnit with nullable parameters, you should use `TestCase(null)` for nullable types. However, since `string` is a reference type and already nullable, you should use `TestCase((string)null)` to explicitly pass a `null` value.

```
    [TestCase((string)null)]
    public void TestCreateClient_ShouldThrowException_IfPasswordIsNull(string certificatePassword)
    {
        // Arrange
        var clientFactory = new ClientFactory(_mockRepositoryWrapper.Object, _alertService.Object);
    
        // Act
        var exception = Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentNullException>(() => clientFactory.CreateClientAsync(
            certificatePassword,
            TestValues.CERTIFICATE_BASE64,
            TestValues.APP_ID,
            TestValues.DOMAIN,
            TestValues.CUSTOMER_ID,
            TestValues.ENVIRONMENT_ID,
            TestValues.LOCALE));
    
        // Assert
        Assert.That(exception.ParamName, Is.EqualTo("certificatePassword can not be null or empty"));

}
```

Comment: Still, I am getting an error 
NUnit1001 The value of the argument at position '0' of type object cannot be assigned to the parameter 'certificatePassword' of type string

Comment: It seems like there might be an issue with the NUnit version or the way NUnit interprets the null value. In your case, since you're dealing with a string (a reference type), passing null should work without any extra casting. @brendandavton

Comment: This only happened when using only latest version of NUnit